# How to Retrieve cURL Data within the URL Endpoint

Tags: php, curl, endpoint

I am trying to create a cURL api, let's say the below is my curl request code, where http://localhost/api/endpoint.php is my endpoint. What would actually be going on, code-wise in the endpoint.php file? How do I actually get the data that is sent via the cURL request, like the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` data, in the endpoint.php page? Thanks.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://localhost/api/endpoint.php';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'alex:password123');

$headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept-Language: en_US'        
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$vars['grant_type'] = 'client_credentials';

$req = http_build_query($vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to these data via the [`$_SERVER` superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php).

Endpoint :

```
<?php

$user     = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; // alex
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];   // password123
```

Comment: Ah yes I see, that's great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your file endpoint.php you can print your posted value using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

after your curl print response like

```
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, print_r($_POST) only shows what values are send via the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS - in this case $vars['grant_type'] = 'client_credentials'; It doesn't show the CURLOPT_USERPWD credentials. However, using the $_SERVER super global as Syscall mentioned, you can get the user and password, thanks.